# index chat mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this chat table:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `support_chat` (
      `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `from` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `to` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `message` text NOT NULL,
      `sent` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `seen` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `from` (`from`),
      KEY `to` (`to`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

basically I need to do a select all the time (3s per user) to check new messages:

```
select id, `from`, message, sent from support_chat where `to` = ? and seen = 0
```

I have 5 million rows, usually 100 users online at the same time. Can I change something to make this table faster? key from and key to is a good option?

Comment: it seems you have 2 accounts. Please read how to merge them: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much you can do by way of indexes to speed up that particular query. You could have a composite index on the to and seen fields but the improvement will be minimal if at all. Why? Because the seen field has very poor cardinality. You only seem to be storing 0 or 1 in it and indexes on such columns are not very usefull. Often it would be faster for the query optimizer to read the data directly.

But here's what you can do [Partition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html):

> ... enables you to distribute portions of individual tables across a
>   file system according to rules which you can set largely as needed. In
>   effect, different portions of a table are stored as separate tables in
>   different locations. The user-selected rule by which the division of
>   data is accomplished is known as a partitioning function,

You can partition your data in such a way that very old data is separated from the new. This will probably give you a big boost. However be aware that if you have a query that fetches old data as well as new data that will be a lot slower.

Here is another thing you can do: Add a limit clause.
You are probably only showing a limited number of messages at any given time. Putting a limit clause will help. Then mysql knows that it doesn't need to look anymore after it has found N rows.

Comment: thank you very much! I will check this partition tip and set limit for my queries!

Comment: `seen` has poor cardinality but `to` has good. Using indexes can improve efficiency dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

Add a multiple column index on to and seen columns in this particular order (to column should be the 1st column in the index). Then run explain select... on your query to see if the new index is used.

Comment: like this? KEY (`to`, `seen`) - should I leave key from and key to?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `seen` column stores 2 values only (`'0'` and `'1'`) and that `to` column stores the recipient of the chat message (email, username), so it can have many more values, I'd use a composite index with `seen` first and `to` second:

```
ALTER TABLE support_chat
  ADD INDEX seen_to_ix
    (seen, `to`) ;
```

A composite index with reversed order `` (`to`, seen) `` would be a good choice, too. It might even be better depending on server load and how often the table is updated. An advantage (if you decide to use the second index), is that you can remove the `` (`to`) `` index.
 Pick and add one of the two indexes and check the performance of your queries again.

Additional notes:

- Using a `varchar(1)` for what is essentially a boolean value is not optimal. Even worse that it is a `utf8mb4` charset. It uses 5 bytes! (1 for the variable and 4 for the single byte!)
  I'd change the type of that column to `tinyint` (and store `0` and `1`) or `bit`.
- Please avoid using reserved words (eg, `from`, `to`) for table and column names.